# Url routing not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my RegisterRoutes method in global.asax:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute("ListBooks",
              "Home/Books/{id}",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Books" },
              new { id = @"\d{2}" });


        }
```

As you can see in the constraint I have specified that the id should be compulsory there of 2 digits. But having specified this, even though I enter just a single digit book id it all still works out pretty well. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint works as expected and url is not matched to the "`ListBooks`" route. But, if you look closer to the "`Default`" route, it has the same signature as the "ListBooks" one - but without constraint. So "`Default`" handles that single digit `id` url. In this case, your route order does not matter, as the "`Default`" will catch single digit `id` url anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your default route should be placed after the other routes, otherwise it would take the precedence.

Comment: I really wonder how this answer got two upvotes - it is wrong. Route ordering has nothing to do with this case. This should have been comment instead

Comment: I think you are wrong. Route ordering is fundamental here, as the *ListBooks* route share with the default route its url/parameters.

Comment: @Erfan, question was about mistakes in route configuration. No matter if Jaggu placed "Default" route first or last, when "ListBooks" constraints are not met (single digit book id), "Default" will handle url anyways.

Comment: @archil: I don't agree. If Jaggu wants to later expand the *ListBooks* route he could easily do that by adjusting its parameters and constraints. But he has to move the *Default* route after the more specific routes...

Comment: That's why i said that your answer should have been comment instead. It does not answer the question, it is just an advice(good one by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
    { 
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 


        routes.MapRoute("ListBooks", 
          "Home/Books/{id}", 
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Books" }, 
          new { id = @"\d{2}" }); 

           routes.MapRoute( 
            "Default", // Route name 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        ); 

    }
```